# Python script to move files stops at 1486 files

Tags: python, file, shutil

I've made a python script which is able to take all the images from a hard drive, then move them to a new folder on the hard drive. This way all images nested deep into random subdirs can be found and placed into this folder.

I have over 830gb of photos to sort.

However, on the 1486th file, the program doesnt crash or freeze, it doesnt finish, it just stops.

Here's my code;

```
    # For each file in the drive
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(drive):
        # For each name in the files
        for file in files:
            if "ImageSorter" in root:
                break;

            file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]

            # Iterate through each supported file extension
            # in our list
            if extension in supported_extensions:
                # If this is the first file being found
                if images_found < 1 and images_moved < 1:
                    # Init the folder
                    init_moveto_folder()

                images_found += 1

                image_dir = os.path.join(root, file);
                # Move the file
                shutil.move(image_dir, drive + "\\ImageSorter\\" + file_name + "_" + str(images_moved + 1) + extension)
                images_moved += 1

                if not extension in found_extensions:
                   found_extensions.append(extension)

                print(images_moved)
        sleep(0.01)
```

If anyone knows what the issue is, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be in the way `os.walk` iterates through the drive, and how the target folder interacts.

Here's a slightly reorganized and simplified version of your code.  The actual move invocation is commented out so you can dry-run the code first, to see it does what you want.  Hope this helps!

```
init_moveto_folder()  # Only check initialization once

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(drive):  # For each file in the drive
    if 'ImageSorter' in root:  # Don't bother with the ImageSorter folder 
        dirs[:] = []  # Clear out the subdirectory list so `os.walk` doesn't go there
        continue
    for file in files:
        file_name, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
        if extension not in supported_extensions:
            found_extensions.append(extension)
            continue  # Extension not supported; continue
        images_found += 1
        source_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        target_path = '%s\\ImageSorter\\%s_%s%s' % (
            drive,
            file_name,
            (images_moved + 1),
            extension,
        )
        print('%s => %s' % (
            source_path,
            target_path,
        ))
        #shutil.move(source_path, target_path)
        images_moved += 1
    sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: This should work great, and thanks for the response! However, I found the issue was the excessive amount of files like; ``Version-0.apversion`` generated by iPhoto which is the folder I'm trying to filter from. The program has to scan each and every single one of these files, which may take a while.

Comment: Ah, alright. You might want to add a progress indicator of some sort then! For instance, `print(root, len(files))` before `for file in files:`, to print the number of files within each folder. :)